# Swapping keys and values with nested value items

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a list of standard names

```
standard = ["Richard","Robert","Nicolas"]
```

and a dictionary of aliases (in this case nicknames)

```
aliases = {standard[0]:["Richard","Rick","Dick","Rich"],
           standard[1]:["Robert","Roberto","Bob"],
           standard[2]:["Nicolas","Nick","Nic"]}
```

I want to make a new dictionary that I can put any of the alias names in as a key and it will return the standard name AKA swap the key and value

My only guess so far was this

```
t = {}
aliases = [t.update(zip(v,[k]*len(v))) for k,v in aliases.items()]
aliases = t
```

is there a neater or more readable way to do this (id prefer not having the temporary dictionary t).

Comment: List comprehensions should only be used if you actually need the list.  In your code, the list consists of `None` values and is obviously useless.  It makes for much more readable code to convert such a list comprehension to a simple for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would be more readable:

```
rev_aliases = {}
for name, nick_list in aliases.iteritems():
    for nick in nick_list:
        rev_aliases[nick] = name
```

If you prefer some form of generator expression you can use these:

Python >= 2.7:

```
rev_aliases = {nick: name 
               for name, nick_list in aliases.viewitems()
               for nick in nick_list}
```

Python < 2.7:

```
rev_aliases = dict((nick, name)
                   for name, nick_list in aliases.iteritems()
                   for nick in nick_list)
```

Comment: I figured loops would be most readable. The generator is what I was trying to concoct. Thanks for a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> standard = ["Richard","Robert","Nicolas"] 
>>> aliases = {standard[0]:["Richard","Rick","Dick","Rich"], 
           standard[1]:["Robert","Roberto","Bob"] ,
           standard[2]:["Nicolas","Nick","Nic"] }
>>> def name(nickname):
        return [n for n in aliases if nickname in aliases[n]]

>>> name('Bob')
['Robert']
>>>
```

List comprehensions are awesome.

Comment: Just fair warning on this, `name()` will iterate over all of `aliases`, which will be much slower than doing a dictionary access as in SvenMarnach's code.

Comment: True, but on the chance there are two nicknames that resolve to the same name ("Chris" -> "Christopher", "Christine"; "Willy" -> "Bill", "William") it won't return all the values. Although modifying his method to handle that would be trivial I suppose, so no matter really

Answer (score 1):

`dict((nick, name) for name, nicks in aliases.iteritems() for nick in nicks)`

Answer (score 0):

A fun way to abuse itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, repeat, chain
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(
        izip(iter(b), repeat(a, len(b)))
        for a, b in aliases.iteritems()))
{'Nicolas': 'Nicolas',
 'Richard': 'Richard',
 'Nic': 'Nicolas',
 'Robert': 'Robert',
 'Dick': 'Richard',
 'Roberto': 'Robert',
 'Nick': 'Nicolas',
 'Rick': 'Richard',
 'Rich': 'Richard',
 'Bob': 'Robert'}
```